# Bottom of edit text is chopped off

Tags: android

I'm making a simple app to start learning how to develop for Android devices. Inside a linear layout (with the height wrapping the content), I've made it so the baseline of the edit text aligns with the text view on the left. As you can see in the first screenshot you can tell the edit text view has focus, but the second one does have focus but you can't tell because the bottom of it has been chopped out.

http://postimg.org/image/rwjph6z7n/

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/v8l2rsmcf/

[image]

How do you fix this?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Stones"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tvStones"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvStones"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Metric Tons"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtStones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvStones"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStones"
        android:hint="1.0"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvTons"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvTons"
        android:hint="1.0"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>
    <View android:id="@+id/view1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnConvert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/convert" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no screenshot, do add it

Comment: add an empty view to the bottom of that with some height, say 5dp

Comment: Can you please clarify how to add an empty view. Cheers :)

Comment: after your last entries xml put this <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

Comment: Sorry, that didn't seem to fix the issue. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what seems working, try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Stones"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tvStones"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvStones"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Metric Tons"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtStones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvStones"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStones"
        android:hint="1.0"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvTons"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvTons"
        android:hint="1.0"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtStones"
        android:textSize="20sp" >

    </EditText>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTons"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the Request Focus to edittext.

Like:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtStones"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tvStones"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStones"
    android:hint="1.0"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```